# Fixing scale to symbols in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, arcgis-10.4, reference-scale

I inserted symbols in a digitized map, but when zoomed out, the symbols get bigger and zoomed in they get smaller.

I know that the scales of symbols can be fixed in ArcGIS Pro, but how can this be done in ArcMap?

I am using version 10.4

Answer (score 0):

It is done in ArcMap by setting a reference scale property on a Data Frame which is more or less the same way it is done in ArcGIS Pro except in the latter it is set as a Map property.

For ArcMap see [Working with data frame reference scales](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/working-with-data-frame-reference-scales.htm).

For ArcGIS Pro see [Map reference scales](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/map-reference-scales.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you dont want to change the reference scale, you can also just uncheck the checkbox you find under layer properties > display > "scale symbols when a reference scale is set"